# How do I install python's sphinx documentation generator in linux?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

And how do I run it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Sphinx website](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/) says:

```
easy_install -U Sphinx
```

If you want that installed in system python you'd probably need elevated permissions with `sudo`:

```
sudo easy_install -U Sphinx
```

If you do not have `easy_install` yet, see http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/EasyInstall

Comment: please take a note of this http://groups.google.com/group/sphinx-dev/msg/77f5b48bca1fd938 if you are encountering any problem.

Answer (score 1):

How do I run it?

http://sphinx-doc.org/tutorial.html#running-the-build

Basically, the easiest way is to start with `sphinx-quickstart` command.

Answer (score 1):

http://showmedo.com/videos/video?name=2910020&fromSeriesID=291

This demo shows how you can use sphinx to document your own program.